# How i can echo php code to codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to filter data when user select click on the button all data is filtered correctly but  tag not work properly.It will show two size but i will need one.
Here is pic of error:

[image]

And here is my model:

```
$result=NULL;
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('sales');
$query = $this->db->get();           

if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
  foreach($query->result() as $all_prod)
  {
     $prod_size=NULL;
     $make_option=NULL;
     $flag=false;
     $i=0;
     $prod_size=$all_prod->sizes;   
     if (strpos($prod_size, ',') !== false) 
     {

         $flag=true;         
     }
    else
     {
         $flag=false;
     }                      
       $result.='<div class="col-lg-4 men-one">
                <img src='.base_url($all_prod->img).' class="img-responsive">
                <div class="row">
                  <p class="col-lg-10" style="margin-top:5px;">'.($all_prod->description).'
                          </p>
                 <span class="btn btn-light glyphicon glyphicon-heart col-lg-1"style="color:#C9302C"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                 <p class="col-lg-3 text-center">Rs:'.($all_prod->sale_price).'
                          </p>
                 <p class="col-lg-3 text-center"><strike>'. ($all_prod->orignal_price).'</strike>
                     </p>         
                  <?php      
                    if('.$flag.'=='.false.')
                     {
                        ?>
                       <form class="col-lg-5">
                       <select class="size_color">
                          <option>Size</option>
                          <option>'.$prod_size.'</option>
                       </select>
                       </form>
                       <?php
                      }
                           else
                           {
                               if('.$flag.'=='.true.')
                               {

                               ?>
                                <form class="col-lg-5">
                                   <select class="size_color">
                                    <option>Size</option>
                                    <?php

                                     while('.$prod_size.'['.$i.']!='.NULL.')
                                     {
                                         if('.$prod_size.'['.$i.']!='.",".')
                                         {
                                             '.$make_option.'='.$make_option.' 
                                             .'.$prod_size.'['.$i.']; 
                                         }
                                         else
                                         {
                                           if('.$prod_size.'['.$i.']=='.",".')
                                           {
                                            ?>
                                            <option>'.$make_option.'</option>
                                            <?php
                                            '.$make_option.'='.NULL.';
                                           }

                                         }
                                         '.$i.'='.$i.'+1;
                                         if('.$prod_size.'['.$i.']=='.NULL.')
                                         {
                                             ?>
                                            <option>'.$make_option.'</option>
                                            <?php
                                            '.$make_option.'=NULL;
                                            '.$flag.'='.false.';
                                         }
                                     }

                                    ?>
                                   </select>
                                </form>
                               <?php                                       
                               }
                           }

                          ?>

                      </div>     
<button class="btn btn-danger col-lg-12" onclick="add_to_cart(id='.$all_prod->id.')">ADD TO CART</button>
                    </div>';

                }
                echo $result;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Thanks In Advance help me i spend too much time tried all possible method that i know but i'm not successful.

Comment: If you want it just printout, use print_r($yourvar);exit(); just for debugging.

Comment: or use var_dump($yourvar);exit(); just for debugging

Comment: why don't you pass it as parameter to view and then use it there as you please?

Comment: basically i call this method through Jquery

Comment: i don't understand your problem and your question isn't very easy to debug. i can say that you can easily make a new controller function that accesses a model function to get db data, then passes that data to a view containing the above view data that is currently in your model. then this controller method you can call via ajax/jquery. that would be mvc. your approach isn't. with relatively little effort you can make it better.